# Multiple Sessions on Applications bein shared unintentionally

Tags: php, session

I have three folders on my project, **students**, **teachers**,**admins**.

Each one of them has a login page that starts a Session when valid then redirects to index.php. And each one of them has **logout.php** that destroys the sessions then redirects to the **login.php**.

**What's my problem?**

If i login on **students**, then open **teachers** or **admin** i'll be logged on these services.  And if i logout in one of them, i'll logout in all of them.

How can i make these sessions operate "individually"?

Comment: Give the sessions a name with `session_name()` and destroy the specific session. So session_name('teachers') -> unset($_SESSION['teachers'])

Comment: uses classes to construct your sessions, then give each one a name. when logging out, instead of destroying the session cast it to null and unset it. to test if logged in, you can use instance of against the session to see if it is an instance of your session class. and yes, it is possible to store class instances in sessions, i've been doing it for years. see more here https://github.com/r3wt/superuser/blob/master/libs/custom/funcs.php#L143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name each session and destroy specific ones.

Using `session_name()` and `unset()` you can have your desired outcome.

So `session_name('teacher')` will register a session for a teacher account.

To destroy that specific session, use `unset($_SESSION['teacher'])`

---

**Some Examples**

Some initialization file or global file..

```
session_name('teacher');
session_start();
```

In logout.php perhaps pass a cookie or query string to identify which session to cancel

```
unset($_SESSION['teacher']);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I should use it like this?

 `session_start();`
 `session_name('admin');`

Also, how do i input data on the session?  
`$_SESSION['login'] = $login`
The code above doesn't work using session_name('admin');

Comment: Declare the name before starting the session. You'll be able to treat the session normally using $_SESSION[]. You can try dumping $_SESSION to see the session data.

Answer (score 0):

Although, from security perspective, log-out event should theoretically clear all user data from session, you can perhaps avoid it by categorising your modules.

If you have the session variable mapped something like this..

```
$_SESSION = array (
                    'student' => array(..),
                    'teacher' => array(..),
                    'admin'   => array(..),
);
```

You can simply unset() one or more of the $_SESSION[..] to clear out particular module. You can also identify which log-out link was clicked by checking $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] variable. Hope it helps.